# Free program(s) to browse and view a mix of raw and Hugin panoramic photos on Windows

Tags: gratis, photography, image-viewer

I've been stitching panoramas for many years in Hugin, mostly for my own viewing. I would think my request/need would be very common, but I can't find a good solution to simply browse a folder/subfolders containing a mix of photos and panoramas.

Something like Irfanview where advancing to the next or last photo is a simple button, but that also handles panoramas. Or something like Google Photos (but cloud-based is a problem for me).

Here are full criteria:

- View, at least thumbnails of, raw images (NEF) and JPG
- View, at least thumbnails of, partial and 360 panoramas created by Hugin. Preferably cylindrical. Bonus if the program can read PTO files directly, such as Hugin's built-in OpenGL preview window. (I know the preview isn't the quality of the final image, but it would suffice.)
- When browsing, needs to be sortable by datetime
- Potential solutions might use more than program, one for browsing and one for viewing. But they must integrate well to quickly browse among photos.
- Free
- Must not be a cloud/web hosted solution, unless there is good synchronization support (and free). I know there are many sites/products that are web-based, but due to the nature of panoramas (large file/pixel sizes), the amount of panoramas I have, and slow internet, it is really very difficult. Also, most web solutions do not view regular photos alongside panoramas.
- Cross-platform or Windows

I have specifically looked for plugins for Irfanview, Lightroom, and Windows Explorer (for thumbnail generation) but haven't found anything.

I'm interested to know what everyone else uses, or if everyone is in the same predicament. Thanks so much.